EvmError: Revert, Foundry when call Payable transfer from testContract with a proxy
I am getting a EvmError: Revert when I am trying to withdraw native token from the first contract to the second contract.
I do not know if this is an Foundry issue because we add in a 3rd contract (testContract) or if it is not possible to withdraw native tokens from a contract to another contract.
Here is a example of two contracts where the FirstContract house 100 ether and the SecondContract is trying to withdraw it using the withdrawNativeToken function.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

contract FirstContract {
    function withdrawNativeToken() public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 thisBalance = address(this).balance;
        address caller = msg.sender;
        payable(caller).transfer(thisBalance);
        return thisBalance;
    }
}

contract SecondContract {
    FirstContract first;

    constructor(address _first) {
        first = FirstContract(_first);
    }

    function withdrawNativeToken() public returns (uint256) {
        return first.withdrawNativeToken();
    }
}


This is the test using Foundry:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {FirstContract, SecondContract} from "../src/FirstAndSecondContract.sol";

contract CounterTest is Test {
    FirstContract firstContract;
    SecondContract secondContract;

    address Caller = vm.addr(0x1);

    function setUp() public {
        firstContract = new FirstContract();
        secondContract = new SecondContract(address(firstContract));

        vm.deal(address(firstContract), 100 ether);
        vm.deal(Caller, 1 ether);
    }

    function test_withdraw() public {
        vm.prank(Caller);
        uint256 amount = secondContract.withdrawNativeToken();
        assertEq(amount, 100 ether);
        assertEq(address(secondContract).balance, 100 ether);
    }
}



You need to add the receive() function in both of your contracts, as both the contracts are expecting to receive native token (or ether) without any data, as explained in this Solidity By Example doc.
So, your revised contracts would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

contract FirstContract {
    function withdrawNativeToken() public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 thisBalance = address(this).balance;
        address caller = msg.sender;
        payable(caller).transfer(thisBalance);
        return thisBalance;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}

contract SecondContract {
    FirstContract first;

    constructor(address payable _first) {
        first = FirstContract(_first);
    }

    function withdrawNativeToken() public returns (uint256) {
        return first.withdrawNativeToken();
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}

NOTE: In the constructor of the SecondContract, the type of the address field used for entering the address of the FirstContract is made as payable because the FirstContract is having the receive() function (i.e., it's expected to be funded with ether as well).

Hahaha how could i miss such a novel mistake x)
Syed you are awesome!!! Thank you once again!

You’re welcome, @Reblixt. Happy coding!
